# Android TrafficStats getTotalRxBytes() returns always zero

Tags: android, networking

Im trying to measure how much bytes my app has received.
Im doing it this way:

```
long receivedBytesBefore = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
...
doSomething();
...
long receivedBytesAfter = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
long receivedBytes = receivedBytesAfter - receivedBytesBefore;
```

My problem is that getTotalRxBytes() always returns 0. So my result is 0 no matter what I do.
I have found out that the method is just reading some textfiles like

```
/sys/class/net/rmnet0/statistics/rx_bytes
```

So I looked into these files and they all contain just "0".

Do I miss something or do I have to activate this function somehow?
Is there another way to measure how much bytes my app has received?

My Android device is a Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 running Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 3):

I can verify this was happening to me as well.

From behavior I've observed, it appears that getTotalRxBytes only works when wifi is connected. But something to be aware of is that if you are trying to get an accurate number of bytes received for a file for example, there seams to be some extra bytes sent.

So if you don't need it to be super accurate. You can use getMobileRxBytes() for when wifi is not active and getTotalRxBytes() for when wifi is active.

Here is a simple example.

ie:

```
    ConnectivityManager connManager;
    connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    long initialBytes = 0;
    long finalBytes = 0;
    long byteDifference = 0;
    boolean onWifi= false;

    if (mWifi.isConnected())
    {
     //wifi connected
     initialBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
     onWifi = true;
    }
    else if (mMobile.isConnected()) 
    {
    //if 3g/4g connected
     initialBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
     onWifi = true;
    }
    else
    {
     //Something funny going on
     Log.e("Error", "Something funny going on");
     return;
    }


// Process whatever you want to process


    if(onWifi)
    {
      finalBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    }
    else
    {
      finalBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
    }

    byteDifference  = finalBytes - initialBytes;
```

Something along these lines. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesnt solve my problem. Im still getting only 0 as result. I have tested the code I have posted in my question on another phone (Nexus One) and it worked just fine. I guess the problem is that my device which is just not compatible.

Answer (score -1):

These may not be supported on your device, and can return `UNSUPPORTED`, which might be 0.

Comment: If it is not supported the function will indeed return UNSUPPORTED. But the documentation states that this is -1 and not 0.  
The problem might be that my device is just not updating the corresponding text-files so they always stay 0.  
Is there any other way to achieve the functionality of getTotalRxBytes?